# ListView.Builder Flutter with filter

Tags: laravel, flutter, rest

Actually I need to list replies on a comment. Code via Laravel Rest API listed me correctly separated comments, but for every comments show same replies list.
I need basically:

Comment id : 1 --> Show all replies related to comment id 1
Comment is : 2 --> Show all replies reletad to comment id 2 etc etc

My code Laravel Rest

```
lic function fetchCommentsreply(Request $request){
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [ 
            'video_id'    => 'required',
            
            
        ],[ 
           'video_id.required'      => 'Video id is required',           
            
            
        ]);

        if (!$validator->passes()) {
            return response()->json(['status'=>'error','msg'=> $this->_error_string($validator->errors()->all()) ]);
        }else{
            $functions = new Functions();
            $limit = 10;
            $replies = DB::table("comments_reply as r")
            ->select(DB::raw("r.*,u.user_id,u.username,u.user_dp,IF(uv.verified='A', true, false) as isVerified"))
            ->join("users as u","r.user_id","u.user_id")
            ->join("comments as c","c.comment_id","r.comment_id")
            ->leftJoin('user_verify as uv', function ($join){
                $join->on('uv.user_id','=','r.user_id')
                ->where('uv.verified','A');
            })
            
            
            
            
            ->where("r.video_id",$request->video_id)
            ->where("r.active",1)
            ->orderBy("r.added_on","desc")
            ->paginate($limit);
            $total_records=$replies->total();                              
            $data= array();
            if(count($replies) > 0) {
                foreach($replies as $key => $reply) {
                    $data[$key]['name'] = $reply->username;
                    if(stripos($reply->user_dp,'https://')!==false){
                        $file_path=$reply->user_dp;
                    }else{
                        $file_path = asset(Storage::url('public/profile_pic/'.$reply->user_id."/small/".$reply->user_dp));
                       
                        if($file_path==""){
                            $file_path=asset('default/default.png');
                        }
                    }
                    $data[$key]['pic'] = $file_path;
                    $data[$key]['reply'] = strip_tags((strlen($reply->reply) > 100) ? mb_substr($reply->reply,0,100).'..' : $reply->reply);
                    $data[$key]['reply_id'] = $reply->reply_id;
                    $data[$key]['comment_id'] = $reply->comment_id;
                    $data[$key]['user_id'] = $reply->user_id;
                    $data[$key]['isVerified'] = $reply->isVerified;
                    $data[$key]['timing'] = Functions::time_elapsed_string($reply->added_on);
                }
            }
            $response = array("status" => "success", "data" => $data,'total_records'=>$total_records);
            return response()->json($response);
        }
    }
```

Flutter view Code

```
Container (
        
        padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: 30,),
        child:   (videoRepo.homeCon.value.replies.length > 0)
            ? Padding( padding: videoRepo.homeCon.value.replies.length > 5
           ? currentUser.value.token != ''
             ? EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 0) : EdgeInsets.zero : EdgeInsets.zero,
           child: ListView.builder(
             shrinkWrap: true,
              controller: videoRepo.homeCon.value.scrollController,
               padding:EdgeInsets.zero,
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                
          itemCount: videoRepo.homeCon.value.replies.length,
           itemBuilder:(context, i) {
            
             return  Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                       // imothek 11.2.0 put here widgtet
                  Container(

                                    child: Card(
                                    margin: EdgeInsetsDirectional.all(0),
                                    color: Colors.transparent,
                                    shape: Border(
                                      top: BorderSide.none,
                                      left: BorderSide.none,
                                      right: BorderSide.none,
                                      bottom: BorderSide.none,
                                    ),
                                    child:  
                                    ListTile(
                                    /*    horizontalTitleGap: -8,
                                       leading:
                                       
                                        videoRepo.homeCon.value.replies.elementAt(i).userDp.isNotEmpty
                                                                            ? GestureDetector (
                                                                              onTap: () {
                                                                                videoRepo.isOnHomePage.value = false;
                                                                                videoRepo.isOnHomePage.notifyListeners();
                                                                                videoRepo.isOnHomePage.value = false;
                                                                                videoRepo.isOnHomePage.notifyListeners();
                                                                                videoRepo.homeCon.value.hideBottomBar.value = false;
                                                                                videoRepo.homeCon.value.hideBottomBar.notifyListeners();
                                                                                videoRepo.homeCon.notifyListeners();
                                                                                Navigator.pushReplacement(
                                                                                  context,
                                                                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                                                                    builder: (context) => videoRepo.homeCon.value.replies.elementAt(i).userId == userRepo.currentUser.value.userId
                                                                                        ? MyProfileView()
                                                                                        : UsersProfileView(
                                                                                            userId: videoRepo.homeCon.value.replies.elementAt(i).userId,
                                                                                          ),
                                                                                  ),
                                                                                );
                                                                              },  
                                                                           child: ClipRRect(
                                                                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                                                                                child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                                                                  imageUrl: videoRepo.homeCon.value.replies.elementAt(i).userDp,
                                                                                  height: 15.0, // imothek original was 60
                                                                                  width: 15.0, // imothek original was 60
                                                                                  fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                                                                                  errorWidget: (a, b, c) {
                                                                                    return Image.asset(
                                                                                      "assets/images/default-user.png",
                                                                                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                                                                    );
                                                                                  },
                                                                                ),
                                                                              ))
                                                                            :  GestureDetector (
                                                                              onTap: () {
                                                                                videoRepo.isOnHomePage.value = false;
                                                                                videoRepo.isOnHomePage.notifyListeners();
                                                                                videoRepo.isOnHomePage.value = false;
                                                                                videoRepo.isOnHomePage.notifyListeners();
                                                                                videoRepo.homeCon.value.hideBottomBar.value = false;
                                                                                videoRepo.homeCon.value.hideBottomBar.notifyListeners();
                                                                                videoRepo.homeCon.notifyListeners();
                                                                                Navigator.pushReplacement(
                                                                                  context,
                                                                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                                                                    builder: (context) => videoRepo.homeCon.value.replies.elementAt(i).userId == userRepo.currentUser.value.userId
                                                                                        ? MyProfileView()
                                                                                        : UsersProfileView(
                                                                                            userId: videoRepo.homeCon.value.replies.elementAt(i).userId,
                                                                                          ),
                                                                                  ),
                                                                                );
                                                                              }, 
                                                                             child: ClipRRect(
                                                                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                                                                                child: Image.asset(
                                                                                  "assets/images/default-user.png", // imothek no photo profile. Orginal was Splash.gif
                                                                                  height: 15.0, // original was 50 imothek
                                                                                  width: 15.0, // original was 50 imothek
                                                                                  fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                                                                                ),
                                    )), */ 

                                      title :  GestureDetector (
                                                                              onTap: () {
                                                                                videoRepo.isOnHomePage.value = false;
                                                                                videoRepo.isOnHomePage.notifyListeners();
                                                                                videoRepo.isOnHomePage.value = false;
                                                                                videoRepo.isOnHomePage.notifyListeners();
                                                                                videoRepo.homeCon.value.hideBottomBar.value = false;
                                                                                videoRepo.homeCon.value.hideBottomBar.notifyListeners();
                                                                                videoRepo.homeCon.notifyListeners();
                                                                                Navigator.pushReplacement(
                                                                                  context,
                                                                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                                                                    builder: (context) => videoRepo.homeCon.value.replies.elementAt(i).userId == userRepo.currentUser.value.userId
                                                                                        ? MyProfileView()
                                                                                        : UsersProfileView(
                                                                                            userId: videoRepo.homeCon.value.replies.elementAt(i).userId,
                                                                                          ),
                                                                                  ),
                                                                                );
                                                                              }, 
                                      child: 
                                     
                                      
                                       RichText(
 // imothek 11.2.0
  text: TextSpan(
    children: [
    
      TextSpan(
        text: "@"+videoRepo.homeCon.value.replies.elementAt(i).userName,
        style: TextStyle(
               fontFamily: 'Poppins',
               fontSize: 12.5,
               fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
              color: themeChange.darkTheme == true ? Colors.grey : Colors.grey
           
      )),
      WidgetSpan(
        child: videoRepo.homeCon.value.replies.elementAt(i).isVerified == true ? 
             SvgPicture.asset(
             "assets/icons/vcomment.svg",
             width: 14,
          color: themeChange.darkTheme == true ? Colors.grey : Colors.grey)
           
          :  SvgPicture.asset(
             "assets/icons/vempty.svg",
             width: 1,) 
      ),
      TextSpan(
        text: " " + videoRepo.homeCon.value.replies.elementAt(i).reply,
        style : TextStyle(
               fontFamily: 'Poppins',
               fontSize: 12.5,
               fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
               color: themeChange.darkTheme == true ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
      )),
      
  ],
                                      )
                                      ),
 
   ),
)
     )
    ),
   
      
      ]
      
      )
      
      );
                                       },
                                                       
                                                          
                                                      ),
                                                    ):Container(),
      ),
```

Flutter controller code

```
 Future<void> getCommentsreply(Video videoObj) async {
    replies = [];
    showLoadMoreReplies = true;
    page = 1;
    scrollController = new ScrollController();
    scrollController1 = new ScrollController();
    final List<CommentreplyData> newReplies =
        await replyRepo.getCommentsreply(videoObj.videoId, page);
    replies.addAll(newReplies);

    if (replies.length == commentObj.countreply) {
      showLoadMoreComments = false;
    }
    scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (scrollController.position.pixels ==
          scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
        if (replies.length != commentObj.countreply && showLoadMoreReplies) {
          loadMore(videoObj);
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Flutter Repo Code

```
ValueNotifier<List<CommentreplyData>> replies = new ValueNotifier([]);
Future<List<CommentreplyData>> getCommentsreply(int videoId, int page) async {
  Uri uri = Helper.getUri('fetch-reply-comments');
  uri = uri.replace(queryParameters: {
    "page": page.toString(),
    "video_id": videoId.toString(),
   
    
  });
  // try {
  Map<String, String> headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + currentUser.value.token,
  };
  var response = await http.post(uri, headers: headers);
  print("commentsreply response.body ${response.body}");
  return parseCommentsreply(json.decode(response.body)['data']);
  /*} catch (e) {
    print("asdasdasdasdasdas $e");
    return [];
  }*/
}
```

Actually I need to list replies on a comment. Code via Laravel Rest API listed me correctly separated comments, but for every comments show same replies list.
I need basically:

Comment id : 1 --> Show all replies related to comment id 1
Comment is : 2 --> Show all replies reletad to comment id 2 etc etc